# Display Barcode in Word

Tags: barcode

I am trying to print Barcode in Word using MergeField and DisplayBarcode.
{DisplayBarcode {MergeField Field1} Code128 \h 500 \t)}
I would like to use the variant A of Code128 which is Code128A how could I use this variant
when a Field code is being used in Word to display the data?

I tried to use {DisplayBarcode {MergeField Field1} Code128A \h 500 \t)} but can't seem to find much difference.